# Deleting row from DataRow[] in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a datarow array `DataRow[] drRequest` with 5 rows.
Then i am iterating each row using `foreach` and deleting rows using

```
foreach (DataRow dr in drRequest) 
{
    dr.Delete();
```

but afterwards the `drRequest.Length` is returning 5 instead of 0.

I can't use `Datatable` , i need to use `DataRow[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DataRow.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't remove this row from the `DataTable`. It just marks this row as "will be deleted from the datasource if you use a DataAdapter and call dataAdapter.Update". If you want to remove it use [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in drRequest) 
{
    dr.Table.Rows.Remove(dr);
}
```

Comment: No benefit of using this row :(

Comment: @Devendra: you cannot modify an array, it has a fixed size. So if you want to do that you have re-assign it: `drRequest = drRequest[0].Table.Select();`

Answer (score 2):

If `drRequest` really is a `DataRow[]`, then it will **always** have length (whatever  it was to start with). Arrays **never change length**. Never. You can `null` a value out of it, but ... that may not be expected by whatever other code is looking at the array later. This is simply a feature of what arrays *are*.

You *might* consider an alternative data structure. For example, you *can* remove things from a `List<T>`. But note that  behind the scenes this involves a shuffle-down. If you are selectively removing things, then `list.RemoveAll(x => {return true to remove, false to keep});` knows how to do this optimally.